# Python regex capturing groups not working for simple expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I would like to get 2 captured groups for a pair of consecutive words. I use this regular expression:

```
r'\b(hello)\b(world)\b'
```

However, searching "hello world" with this regular expression yields no results:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b(hello)\b(world)\b')
m =  regex.match('hello world') # m evaluates to None.
```

Comment: This is because you're looking for the string `<boundary>hello<boundary>world<boundary>`, but you're trying to match on the string `<boundary>hello<boundary><space><boundary>world<boundary>`.

Comment: For your use case, I would recommend using `re.findall` or `re.finditer` instead.

Comment: Makes sense, word boundaries shouldn't be equated with spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow for space between the words:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\b(hello)\s*\b(world)\b')
>>> regex.match('hello world')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f6fcc249140>
>>>
```

#### Discussion

The regex `\b(hello)\b(world)\b` requires that the word `hello` end exactly where the word `world` begins but with a word break `\b` between them.  That cannot happen.  Adding space, `\s`, between them fixes this.

If you meant to allow punctuation or other separators between `hello` and `world`, then that possibility should be added to the regex.